# How to innerHTML a jsx element on react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, innerhtml

I've been trying to make a login form that when u click register, the register button becomes a loading icon and if it gets a `false` response from the server it loads the button back again instead of the loading spinner, but i got a problem that it only shows [object Object] instead of the button when it is supposed to remove the loading spinner and show the register button again (using `innerHTML`), so here is the statement i used to render the button, spinner:

```
     onSubmit = () => {
            document.getElementById('error-alert').innerHTML = "";
            document.getElementById('sumbit-btn').innerHTML = ` //rendering the loading spinner
            <span class="btn btn-light border-1 border-dark mdi mdi-loading mdi-spin mdi-24px"></span>`;
            fetch("my server link here", {
              method: 'post',
              headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
              body: JSON.stringify({
                email: this.state.email,
                password: this.state.password,
                name: this.state.name
              })
            })
              .then(response => response.json())
              .then(user => {
                if (user.id) {   // if the input is correct (response true from the server)
                  this.props.loadUser(user)
                  this.props.onRouteChange('home');
}



 else {  //if the response is false from the server


    ///////////////   this is the innerHTML i mean:   //////////
                  document.getElementById('sumbit-btn').innerHTML =
                    <div
                      className="btn btn-light border-1 border-dark"
                      onClick={this.onSubmit}
                    >Register
                  </div>
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

                }
              })
          }
```

note that this codeblock is outside the `render(){}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way would be to store a boolean in state and then make a ternary in the render. Change the boolean depending on your needs.

```
 onSubmit = () => {
        document.getElementById('error-alert').innerHTML = "";
        this.setState({showLoading: true});
        <span class="btn btn-light border-1 border-dark mdi mdi-loading mdi-spin mdi-24px"></span>`;
        fetch("my server link here", {
          method: 'post',
          headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            email: this.state.email,
            password: this.state.password,
            name: this.state.name
          })
        })
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(user => {
            if (user.id) {   // if the input is correct (response true from the server)
              this.props.loadUser(user)
              this.props.onRouteChange('home');
 } else {
   this.setState({showLoading: false});
}
render(){
   return(
     <div>{show ? 
                    <Loading/> 
                    :
                    <div
                      className="btn btn-light border-1 border-dark"
                      onClick={this.onSubmit}
                    >Register
                  </div>
          }
  )
}
```

Comment: Or if you are just trying to add a className to the button you could do the same, but just with the ternary inside of className.

Comment: Yeah i actually solved by adding a new state element and creating a new component for the button it self and did the if statement inside the submit component, the class method looks good too lol thanks